# create a tree from database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a SQL table with the following structure for example:

```
 name      last-name
 -------------------
 maria     moh adam
 rami      moh adam
 sabi      ali adam
 mary      joh ali
```

How I  can create this tree represented below:

```
                    adam
                    /  \
                 moh    ali
                 /      /  \
             maria    sabi  joh
                             |
                             mary
```

I have tried with this two different methed .. but it does not work:

```html
private void addniv1(Node root,Node tree) {
   int cols =3;
  Node niv=null;
   Node niv1=null;
     
   TableModel model = table.getModel();
   int row = model.getRowCount();
   Object[] values = new Object[ row ];
   for ( int rows = 1; rows < row; rows++ ) 
    {
    values[ rows ] = model.getValueAt( rows, 3 );
    String pere[]= ((String) values[rows]).split(" ");
    String gr_fath=pere[2];
    String father=pere[0];
    values[ rows ] = model.getValueAt( rows, 0 );
    String fils=(String) values[ rows ];
    if(root.getData().equals(gr_fath)) {
      niv=new Node(father);
      root.addChild(niv); 
      AddChilds(root,niv);
       } }
   //*********************************************
   private void AddChilds(Node tree, Node child) {
 String str=child.getData()+" "+"bn"+" "+tree.getData();
 String SQL="select distinct * from Base1 where father='"+str+"' ";
          ResultSet rs;
    try {
     rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
    while(rs.next())
     {
       Node child3= new Node(rs.getString("prenom"));
       child3.setParent(child);
        child.addChild(child3);
        AddChilds(child,child3);
            }
          
    } catch (SQLException e) {
     
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my problem is: -when i have the same last-name..the code duplicates the node father and son
 the exexution:

```html
                           adam
                    /        |            \
                 moh        moh          ali
                 /\         /  \         /  \
             maria rami   rami maria   sabi  joh
                                              |
                                             mary
```

Comment: can you share the error which is coming??

Comment: Can you guarantee that all elements result in the same root-name. I mean, what should happen if for instance the second element was named "sabi ali eve"? In that case you'ld have 2 root-names. "adam" and "eve".

Comment: for working with trees it is always best to use [**`Nested Set Models`**](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)